# non-outlined mesh in Blender 2.92 shows up in boolean modifier

Tags: modifiers, objects

There is an mesh in my Blender 2.92 file, which does not appear in the Outliner but somehow appears as a possible selection in a Boolean Modifier.
[image: The Mesh does not show up in the Outliner, but shows up as a selection for the Boolean Modifier.]

Comment: Maybe it's parented to another object? When an object is parented to another, it's placed 'inside' the parent in the hierarchy in the outliner.

Comment: @AlexandreMarcati It wasn't. I checked basically every object, and it did not show up once.

Comment: That's weird. Have you tried typing the name of the object in the outliner search bar?

Comment: @AlexandreMarcati I also have done that.